# Is it possible to have fast web scraping capabilities when a user performs a query

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping

I am working on a project and want to extract data from a website when a user issues a query. I am concerned about the performance of the application. Is there a way to speed the time it takes from the moment a user issues a query and receives a response that is scraped from a website? As an example, if I wanted to scrape twitter and retrieve the number of likes, is there a way to reduce the time it takes from when the user issues a query about the number of likes a post has to the response?

My current plan for scraping websites is as follows:

1. User issues query for a website (twitter)
2. Headless (preloaded from a pool of) browser loads website
3. Perform data scraping and retrieve the desired data
4. Package this data in a response to the user
5. User retrieves response

In the past I have used beautiful soup to perform the scraping, but I am looking for an alternative that can be used for production level scraping. Note: I am also planning on indexing the websites that i scrape since I anticipate users retrieving similar websites.

Comment: Try using APIs instead of scraping whenever available. Gather the information in advance on your server already instead of retrieving it when requested.

Comment: I would either use websites own API as they are faster and reliable with a cost or find most query sites and perform pre-scrapying with tools like https://apify.com/

Comment: I agree! I would preferably want to use a sites API, but often sites do not have their own so I have to resort to scraping :/ which can be unreliable

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the performance of a system like yours can be affected by the number of user requests. That's why I think that this approach of parsing by user request will not work quickly. There are several obvious reasons, including the fact that you cannot guarantee that the source site is available or that the request limit has been exceeded. Also, there might be some latency issues due to your users being from different regions of the world, etc.

In general, to build a content aggregation system, you need to implement [4 stages](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358426964_Research_on_the_methods_of_building_content_aggregation_systems):

1. Aggregation, which involves crawling data source across the web. At this stage, high-performance web crawler agents are required to deal with huge amounts of data.
2. Pre-processing stage, which often includes HTML markup removal, lowercasing, stop words removal, stemming and lemmatization, keywords extraction.
3. Processing stage, at which aggregated data is grouped (by meaning, relevance, source, etc.).
4. Output stage, at which the processed data is returned.

As you can see, it's about building a high-performance distributed system, not about choosing a faster parser. The aggregation process must be performed offline with a periodic call to the crawler. User requests should be processed using aggregated data.